# how to find a library that's being included in a lua application

Tags: linux, include, lua

I'm kinda new to linux so you'll have to pardon my question if it's really basic. I have a code snippet that includes the following line:

```
    require("axf.sf")
```

I am trying to find the file that contains this code. 
I've tried the following commands on my server:

```
    find / -name axf.sf
    find / -name axf.sf*
```

But I can't locate it. I know the code exists because the program works.

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua, like many languages, has the concept of a "path" to search for required modules.

It can be configured by several means, but it's usually something like

```
./?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua
```

(you can verify if your's is different by checking typing `=package.path` at a Lua prompt)

The default package searcher first takes the package name ("axf.sf" in your example) and replaces each dot with the OS's directory separator.  ("axf/sf" in your example, since you're on Linux).  Then it replaces the `?` on each pattern with the transformed package name, and uses the first one that exists on your system.

so, it would search for

```
./axf/sf.lua
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/axf/sf.lua
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/axf/sf/init.lua
/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/axf/sf.lua
/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/axf/sf/init.lua
/usr/share/lua/5.1/axf/sf.lua
/usr/share/lua/5.1/axf/sf/init.lua
```

Comment: And if the module is question is a C module then it searches package.cpath instead.

Comment: There is also [`package.searchpath`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-package.searchpath) which can tell you the exact path of the file.  E.g. `=package.searchpath('axf.sf', package.path) or package.searchpath('axf.sf', package.cpath)`